# Can anybody recognise this equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions

I just wonder if the following equation is a known special function?
$$\left(u(1-u^2)\frac{d^2}{du^2}-(u^2+1)\frac{d}{du}-\frac{au}{(1-u^2)}-\frac{bu^3}{(1-u^2)}+c\right)G(u,u')=0,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are constants and $u\in(-1,1)$. Can someone recognise it? Thank you very much!

Comment: What $u'$ means ?